# Openshift MySQL event_scheduler

Tags: mysql, openshift

After restarting or updating my Openshift application, the MySQL cartridge starts with event_scheduler off.

I tried adding an environment variable to have it started in "on" mode (as suggested in the my.cnf file), but it still doesn't work

```
>rhc env-list app-name
RSA 1024 bit CA certificates are loaded due to old openssl compatibility
OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_EVENT_SCHEDULER=on
```

So my question is, how to make it so the event_scheduler is always on, even after restart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_EVENT_SCHEDULER` does not seem to be supported. The supported configurable values are listed in the `my.cnf` file below the `# Configurable Values:` line.

If you's like to see that implemented into the MySQL add-on cartridge, you can add the idea to http://openshift.uservoice.com and get others to vote on it.